# Properties of metric $d$ in a connected space $X$

Tags: metric-spaces

If $X$ is a connected metric space, and $p$ is a cut point, such that $X-\{p\} = B \cup E$, and $B,E$ are open disjoint subsets of $X$, can I say that the metric $d$ on $X$ has to make it true that for every point in $x \in B$ and $y \in E$, $d(x,p) < d (x,y)$?

Comment: What are $U$ and $V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The answer is No. Consider a "V" shape in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with origin as the turning point and with two branches steep enough. Then let $p$ be origin.